# Can I use a NamedJdbcTemplate for this use case?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I made a method called calculate which uses a query with a select count* and returns a boolean if the count is equal to 90.

1. Can I wrap the  `namedJdbcTemplate.update` call in an `if` statement to check the value of count as seen below?
2. I am getting error that states I cannot use the update method on the namedJdbcTemplate:

```
Method executeUpdate cannot be used for query. ERRORCODE=-4476, SQLSTATE=null; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10104][10942][4.14.113] Method executeUpdate cannot be used for query. ERRORCODE=-4476, SQLSTATE=null
```

Is there a better way to check whether the query returns 90 like this? :

```
if(namedJdbcTemplate.update(CALCULATE_QUERY, paramMap) == 90)
```

```
  private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;

public Assessment process(Assessment assessment) throws Exception {
        if (calculate(assessment) == true){
            return assessment;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
}
    

    public boolean calculate(Assessment assessment){
        final String CALCULATE_QUERY ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +
                "(SELECT BAL_AS_OF_DT FROM MYTABLE " +
                "WHERE CUST_UID = :customerId )";

        Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        paramMap.put("customerId", assessment.getCustUid());
        try{
      
            if(namedJdbcTemplate.update(CALCULATE_QUERY, paramMap) == 90){
                return true;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.error(e.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your query to return boolean, something like this:

```
final String CALCULATE_QUERY ="SELECT COUNT(*) = 90 FROM MYTABLE WHERE CUST_UID = :customerId )";
```

then you can use `queryForObject` method:

```
return namedJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(CALCULATE_QUERY, paramMap, Boolean.class);
```

Comment: SQL does not like the **=90** it breaks the query